# Rename folder in Ant

Tags: ant

we are packaging our application through ant.

We are having one java file which will create list of folder with some of the files inside when we execute through java in ant.

for e.g
There is a folder named 'localized' which be generated when i execute a java program. Inside localized folder, we will be having many folder for e.g. us_abc, us_def, us_ghj.

once above folder is generated, i need to rename the folder from us_abc to abc, us_def to def and so on. After renaming i will bundle it in tar file.

Note:
number of folder and folder name is dynamic and i cant hard code it in move command in ant. I m not the owner of the java file so i cant change the file currently to change the folder name from us_abc to abc during generation itself.

Is there any way to rename the folder in ANT? I want it with Ant Core and dont want to install any extra jars or plug-in.

```
         localizaed/
            us_abc/a.jsp
            us_def/b.jsp
```

Expected:

```
        localizaed/
            abc/a.jsp
            def/b.jsp
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a mapper

```
<target name="do">
    <move todir="localizaed2">
        <fileset dir="localizaed">
        </fileset>
        <mapper type="glob" from="us_*" to="*"/>
    </move>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ant move command will allow you to do this.  Directories and files are both viewed the same by this command.

```
<move file="mySourceDirName" tofile="myTargetDirName"/>
```

So:

```
<move file="us_abc" tofile="abc"/>
```

It would be best to also use a path variable to ensure you are in the directory the /localized/us_* directories are in. Just a precaution.